# Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'eslint

Tags: node.js, axios

I had install Axios and use (import Axios from 'Axios';)

but it shows me this error.

Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'eslint

Comment: Please add some code of your current configuration, is this a webpack setup?

Comment: and I'm using parcel-bundler but I did not bundle the project yet

Comment: `NODE_ENV=development PORT=3000 DATABASE=mongodb+srv://ahmedtalal:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.j4efe.mongodb.net/twdtest?retryWrites=true&w=majority DATABASE_PASSWORD=2345gffh@qwe JWT_SECRET=my-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret-twd JWT_EXPIRES_IN=90d JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN=90 EMAIL_USERNAME=44cc1c7c117303 EMAIL_PASSWORD=57wccd1c2ebb1e EMAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io EMAIL_PORT=25`

Comment: I tried `type=" module"` in package.json, but all of require did not work